# Why do Germans write and say 23 as 'Dreiundzwanzig' instead of 'zwanzig (und) drei'?

Tags: etymology

In most languages in Europe 23 is written as twenty-three, only German and Dutch it is spoken and written like three-twenty. What is the reason/cause of that?

Comment: It used to be the same in English.

Comment: Oh, and when was it changed and why?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/19th-century-english-texts-occasionally-use-germanic-style-number-words-such-as http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218077/where-do-these-numbers-come-from-and-do-we-still-use-them http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2014/11/lexicon_valley_the_history_and_evolution_of_writing_out_numbers_in_the_english.html

Comment: @Carsten Comments shouldn't be used as answer substitutes.

Comment: @hiergilt I had hoped that the links might help to answer the question or more likely to clarify the question. So far the only answer that I could give would be “that has always been the Germanic way”. I do not know if that would be satisfactory. Anyway, I remembered the Lexicon Valley episodes, but none of the details.